# html - php echo row repeatedly (table reverse)

Tags: php

I am trying to echo some data in table like this

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th> Subject </th
            <th> <?php echo $row["sub"] ?> </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rate 1</td>
            <td><?php echo $row["rating1"]?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rate 2</td>
            <td><?php echo $row["rating2"]?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

OUTPUT:

```
Subject  |  Math
Rate 1   |  5
Rate 2   |  5
Subject  |  English
Rate 1   |  5
Rate 2   |  5
```

**I WANT LIKE THIS**

```
Subject  | Math | English
Rate 1   |  5   |  5
Rate 2   |  5   |  5
```

Comment: Can you please give `var_dump` of array you prepared?

Comment: You have an unclosed tag in `<th> Subject </th`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code, It will help you.

```
<table>
<tbody>
 <tr>
   <th> Subject </th>
   <?php
   foreach($result as $row)
   {
    echo '<th>'.$row["sub"].'</th>';
   }
   ?>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Rate1</td>
    <?php
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        echo '<td>'.$row["rating1"].'</td>';
    }
    ?>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Rate2</td>
    <?php
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        echo '<td>'.$row["rating2"].'</td>';
    }
    ?>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would like the $row["sub"] as a table header. :)

Comment: Op wants all `rating1` on one row and `rating2` on a second row. Took me a while to understand too.

Comment: Yes :) thats all I wanted to express.

Answer (score 0):

First put your data together, then output:

```
$sub=[];
$rate1=[];
$rate2=[];

foreach($result as $row){
  $sub[]  =$row['sub'];
  $rate1[]=$row['rate1'];
  $rate2[]=$row['rate2'];
}
```

Then you can output:

```
echo '<tr> <td> '.implode('</td><td>', $sub ).' </td><tr> ';
echo '<tr> <td> '.implode('</td><td>', $rate1 ).' </td><tr> ';
echo '<tr> <td> '.implode('</td><td>', $rate2 ).' </td><tr> ';
```